# What authentication options do you have in django?

Tags: python, django

I'm new to django, are there many choices for user authentication (in terms of plugins) or is there just one way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's one correct way to [log a user in](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#how-to-log-a-user-in), but there are [many, may, many potential authdbs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#other-authentication-sources).

Comment: nice is there something that supports login as normal + facebook + twitter + openid etc?

Comment: I've not used one, but I have heard of django-socialauth.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to allow your users to signup/singin with Twitter, Facebook and OpenID (i.e. Google and others), I suggest [django-socialregistration](https://github.com/flashingpumpkin/django-socialregistration). A few months ago when I did a research it was the most straightforward and complete such library out there, and now it looks like it's I was right as it's gaining momentum in Django community.

#### Edit

Django gurus also use django-socialregistration: http://www.revsys.com/officehours/2010/nov/05/#question27 :-)

Answer (score 1):

The socialauth module provides you one click login options via various OpenId Providers like (Google, Yahoo, custom etc) + Twitter + Facebook. Read more about socialauth at http://uswaretech.com/blog/2009/08/django-socialauth-login-via-twitter-facebook-openid-yahoo-google/ and source is on github https://github.com/uswaretech/Django-Socialauth

Answer (score 1):

You have many choices to choose from. You can use Django's default user authentication, Django-OpenID, and a lot more. One of the easiest app to setup is 'django_openid_auth'. You can view the snippets here: http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2183/